# Await request in Express js

Tags: javascript, typescript, express

I need  await request in app.post and use request outside function. I wrote some code, it works, but sometimes it freezes

```
receivePost(url, response) {
const app = this.app;
return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
  app.post(url, async (req, res) => {
    res.send(response)
    try {
      resolve(req.body);
    } catch {
      reject();
    }
    req.end();
  });
});
}
```

The problem arises when I am trying get request twice and more.
I try restart Server with function this.app.listen and this.server.destroy between usage.

Comment: where do you need the ```await``` keyword? i don't see any on the code, could you update it please?

Comment: I need await in calling code, for example
`async receiveMessage(response: IResponse) : Promise<IRequest> {
    return await this.receivePost('/', response)
  }`

Comment: This seems an odd way to bind a callback to post request. I think you should check event listening and emitting...